# Debug.Listeners and Trace.Listeners are equal by reference

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, listener, trace

By experimenting a little with `Debug` and `Trace` classes, I came upon the fact that `Debug.Listeners` is referencially equivalent to `Trace.Listeners`.

So these happen

```
Console.WriteLine(Debug.Listeners == Trace.Listeners); // true
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(Debug.Listeners, Trace.Listeners)); // true
```

This makes impossible to log Debug and Trace messages differently.

Is this a bug, or a feature; and more importantly: why does it work like that?

Comment: I don't know whether it's a bug that was noticed too late, or a feature that just isn't well explained, but it is at least [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners?view=netframework-4.7.2): "The `Listeners` collection is shared by both the `Debug` and the `Trace` classes; adding a trace listener to either class adds the listener to both."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is feature (in sense it is documented - [Trace.Listeners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners?view=netframework-4.7.2)). You have list of listeners that send logged messages to some destination (trace window, console, file,...).

You can separate control whether `Debug.xxx` and `Trace.xxx` statement do anything by defining/un-defining corresponding symbols. Normally your "Debug" build defines both `DEBUG` and `TRACE` while "Release" configuration only defines `TRACE` conditional compilation symbol. You can see that in project's properties on "Build" tab.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a *good* feature to me - while you can configure separately whether they're enabled, you still can't configure them to go to different outputs.

Comment: @JonSkeet no one even knows that .Net has built in tracing... :)  I personally think it is easier to configure for basic projects that way. For anything more complex people use some other libraries anyways. (thanks for finding the link - added to the post)